# Where to define the -shouldAutorotate method in iOS 6?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, autorotate

I am trying to define the shouldAutorrotate method, but I don't know where to define it as it's never being called. I have a UITabBarController, with three tabs (each one, with a root navigation controller) in my project. My aim is to disable autorotation in some specfic cases.

Thank you!

Comment: Ok understood, the reason is that I can't accept my own answer until a couple of days have gone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, solved. What I did: In my topmost navigation controller I defined

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];}
```

and then, in my next viewController

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {return NO;}
```

Thanks guys!!!

Comment: If you define a category for UINavigationController and/or UITabBarController that has the `-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {return [self.visibleViewController shouldAutorotate];}` method then you can use this pattern regardless of having a subclassed navigation controller anywhere in your app.

Answer (score 1):

you can write that method in `viewcontroller.m` file, for which you want to disable autorotation
Here is the code for iOS 6:

```
#ifdef IOS_NEWER_OR_EQUAL_TO_6
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
   return NO;
}
#endif
```

Comment: if you want you application to run in IOS or lower version, than if you write #ifdef than it won't through error

Comment: if you want your app for IOs 6 only, than you can remove that one

Comment: There’s no harm in having the method in older iOS versions, it will simply not get called.

Comment: yes, you are correct but for lower versions we need to write - (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation method, so I use this approach wherever required, for understanding purpose also

Answer (score 0):

Read the [iOS 6.0 Release Notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-6_0/index.html):

> Autorotation is changing in iOS 6. In iOS 6, the
>   shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method of UIViewController is
>   deprecated. In its place, you should use the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: and shouldAutorotate methods.
>
> More responsibility is moving to the app and the app delegate. Now,
>   iOS containers (such as UINavigationController) do not consult their
>   children to determine whether they should autorotate. By default, an
>   app and a view controller’s supported interface orientations are set
>   to UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll for the iPad idiom and
>   UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown for the iPhone idiom.
>
> A
>   view controller’s supported interface orientations can change over
>   time—even an app’s supported interface orientations can change over
>   time. The system asks the top-most full-screen view controller
>   (typically the root view controller) for its supported interface
>   orientations whenever the device rotates or whenever a view controller
>   is presented with the full-screen modal presentation style. Moreover,
>   the supported orientations are retrieved only if this view controller
>   returns YES from its shouldAutorotate method. The system intersects
>   the view controller’s supported orientations with the app’s supported
>   orientations (as determined by the Info.plist file or the app
>   delegate’s application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:
>   method) to determine whether to rotate.
>
> The system determines whether
>   an orientation is supported by intersecting the value returned by the
>   app’s supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow: method with the value
>   returned by the supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most
>   full-screen controller.
>
> The setStatusBarOrientation:animated: method
>   is not deprecated outright. It now works only if the
>   supportedInterfaceOrientations method of the top-most full-screen view
>   controller returns 0. This makes the caller responsible for ensuring
>   that the status bar orientation is consistent.

So I would first try to implement the behaviour in the app delegate. If that’s too coarse for your use case, I would try to implement the `-shouldAutorotate` (note the single `r`!) method for the individual content view controllers. If that does not work (see the quote above), implement this method in your container controller, ie. the tab bar controller or the navigation controller.

See also the WWDC 2012 Session #236, [The Evolution of View Controllers on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=236).

Comment: -(BOOL)shouldAutorotate keeps without being called. I tried in TabBarController.m and some ViewController.m, but nothing. Any ideas?

Comment: It has to be called at least on the topmost fullscreen view controller. Most probably you’re adding the code to the wrong class. I would place a breakpoint say in `-viewWillAppear` to make sure the class gets used where I expect it to. Also, make sure you’re not prohibiting other orientations in `Info.plist`.